# How do I see the unread messages in Messages.app?

Tags: ichat

Here’s an example of Messages.app displaying unread messages in the title bar:

[image]

What I’m curious about is how do I find these unread messages without scrolling around and hunting them out?

Comment: How do I indicate to a mod that I’d like this question migrated?

Comment: @Deltik [please do not prod users to migrate their questions if they're on-topic for Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2967/is-it-okay-to-inform-users-to-stop-promoting-apple-se-when-a-question-is-fine-to).

Comment: @EdwardOcampo-Gooding if you would _prefer_ to have your question [apple.se] I can migrate it for you, but you are in no way required to move it - questions about OS X are 100% permitted on Super User.